# Dynamic html is not getting rendered by jQuery.tmpl

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates

I am using a jQuery template to render some dynamic data. A simplified version of what I am trying to do can be seen below:

```
var data = [{html:<i>html</i>}, {html:<b>html2</b>}];
var tmpl =  $.tmpl(<div>${html}</div>, data);
$("#someContainer").html(tmpl);
```

I want to render HTML as HTML (HTML in bold) but somehow it renders as plain text (`<.b>html<./b>`). Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using the `{{html}}` marker:

```
var tmpl =  $.tmpl('<div>{{html html}}</div>', data);
```

See docs here: [html marker](http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-html/)

_note: it's html html twice because your var is named that

Comment: The strings in data needs quotes too, doesn't it?

Comment: it does, but he said it was simplified, so i just assumed he had it working

Comment: it should work but strangely it doesn't

var data = [{title: "name", html: "<b>bold me</b>"}]
var tmpl = $.tmpl('<div>{{html html}}</div>', data);
$('#cont').html(tmpl)

i test with this data and still same old plain text :?

Comment: ahhhh my reset.css was normalizing all the html sorry for trouble and thanks for reference